# Any reason to disable session functionality in PHP if not being used?

Tags: php, session

Our architecture is such that we handle cookies and sessions internally instead of using the built in PHP functionality.

The PHP documentation states: "Session support is enabled in PHP by default. If you would not like to build your PHP with session support, you should specify the --disable-session option to configure."

My question is, is there any reason to disable it? Does session support add any overhead to an at-scale application if it's enabled but not being used?

Many thanks.

Comment: My theory is that every small thing that's enabled add a bit of overhead; the question is how big. If you're super obsessed with speed optimizations and such, I'd recommend disabling it, but if you don't mind that extra millisecond, you're fine. [Disclaimer: I haven't actually disabled sessions before, so not sure how much it adds, but I imagine it can't possibly be *that* much]

Comment: "If you're super obsessed with speed optimizations and such" Yes! :)

Comment: code that's not used/executed has no cpu overhead, it'll just occupy some extra disk and memory space.

Comment: Right, so is anything used/executed if it isn't disabled? Initialization, garbage collection, anything?

Comment: `"If you're super obsessed with speed optimizations and such" Yes! :)` So why an interpreted language? Also, did you check if your actual session handling architecture is better than php native one? You're gaining nothing if you spare a millisecond here and then throw away resources somewhere else. Microptimization has a purpose in some contexts, not everywhere

Comment: @DamienPirsy good question! We're actually a tiered application and are using a different language in the business logic, and this is where sessions are handled. PHP is simply our UI/UX layer.

Comment: i suspect that if you disable it, your php executable will compile to a few bytes smaller. so it should load a few nano seconds faster when booting up. :p

Answer (score 0):

Only performance overhead that i can think of would be if you are running default php setup, there is 1% chance per request, that session garbage collector will run. Since there are no sessions initialized by PHP I think there is no measurable overhead - just couple of IO operations (to check whether there are any files in sessions directory, which will be empty anyways) per 100 requests.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-divisor